# Load page as not secure HTTPS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have an extension which parse some website. I have a mixed content error which I can't resolve when scanning. I saw that some guys solve this problem but don't know how. Before they run extension on website, it's secure - http://prntscr.com/be8syo but after click scan webpage reloading and became not fully secure - http://prntscr.com/be8t29
Anyone has idesa how to do this with Javascript? And when page is not fully secure extension works good because all errors became as warnings.

Comment: No javascript related. SSL is applied in https protocol, so is server-side. This should be closed as offtopic.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude guys which build these extension don't have access to server side, so if you don't know how to do this, probably other will know

Comment: I don't need code examples how to do this, just need ideas how can realize it

Comment: Do you expect an answer to this question? There's no details, only two screenshots of a little part of the screen that shows the page protocol. Since you are not sharing the code that you use to retrieve that mixed content, how can we answer that? That's the reason why this is offtopic (read the help center for more info).

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I suppose I know how to do this. As I said previously I just need to know how I can make page work not as secure, probably I know how, and I did it, but have some errors in console.. When I will solve this I will write here..